# bookinfo example app crashes on istio

Tags: docker, kubernetes, istio

I am trying to evaluate istio and trying to deploy the bookinfo example app provided with the istio installation. While doing that, I am facing the following issue.

```
Environment: Non production
1. Server Node - red hat enterprise linux 7 64 bit VM [3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64]
   Server in customer secure vpn with no access to enterprise/public DNS.
2. docker client and server: 1.12.6
3. kubernetes client - 1.9.1, server - 1.8.4
4. kubernetes install method: kubeadm.
5. kubernetes deployment mode: single node with master and slave.
6. Istio install method:
    - istio version: 0.5.0
    - no SSL, no automatic side car injection, no Helm.
    - Instructions followed: https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/quick-start.html
    - Cloned the istio github project - https://github.com/istio/istio.
    - Used the istio.yaml and bookinfo.yaml files for the installation and example implementation.
```

Issue:

The installation of istio client and control plane components went through fine.

The control plane also starts up fine.

However, when I launch the bookinfo app, the app's proxy init containers crash with a cryptic "iptables: Chain already exists" log message.

```
ISTIO CONTROL PLANE
--------------------
$ kubectl get deployments,pods,svc,ep -n istio-system
NAME                   DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deploy/istio-ca        1         1         1            1           2d
deploy/istio-ingress   1         1         1            1           2d
deploy/istio-mixer     1         1         1            1           2d
deploy/istio-pilot     1         1         1            1           2d

NAME                               READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
po/istio-ca-5796758d78-md7fl       1/1       Running   0          2d
po/istio-ingress-f7ff9dcfd-fl85s   1/1       Running   0          2d
po/istio-mixer-69f48ddb6c-d4ww2    3/3       Running   0          2d
po/istio-pilot-69cc4dd5cb-fglsg    2/2       Running   0          2d

NAME                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                            AGE
svc/istio-ingress   LoadBalancer   10.103.67.68    <pending>     80:31445/TCP,443:30412/TCP                                         2d
svc/istio-mixer     ClusterIP      10.101.47.150   <none>        9091/TCP,15004/TCP,9093/TCP,9094/TCP,9102/TCP,9125/UDP,42422/TCP   2d
svc/istio-pilot     ClusterIP      10.110.58.219   <none>        15003/TCP,8080/TCP,9093/TCP,443/TCP                                2d

NAME               ENDPOINTS                                                         AGE
ep/istio-ingress   10.244.0.22:443,10.244.0.22:80                                    2d
ep/istio-mixer     10.244.0.20:9125,10.244.0.20:9094,10.244.0.20:15004 + 4 more...   2d
ep/istio-pilot     10.244.0.21:443,10.244.0.21:15003,10.244.0.21:8080 + 1 more...    2d


BOOKINFO APP
-------------
$ kubectl get deployments,pods,svc,ep
NAME                    DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deploy/details-v1       1         1         1            1           2d
deploy/productpage-v1   1         1         1            1           2d
deploy/ratings-v1       1         1         1            1           2d
deploy/reviews-v1       1         1         1            1           2d
deploy/reviews-v2       1         1         1            1           2d
deploy/reviews-v3       1         1         1            1           2d

NAME                                 READY     STATUS                  RESTARTS   AGE
po/details-v1-df5d6ff55-92jrx        0/2       Init:CrashLoopBackOff   738        2d
po/productpage-v1-85f65888f5-xdkt6   0/2       Init:CrashLoopBackOff   738        2d
po/ratings-v1-668b7f9ddc-9nhcw       0/2       Init:CrashLoopBackOff   738        2d
po/reviews-v1-5845b57d57-2cjvn       0/2       Init:CrashLoopBackOff   738        2d
po/reviews-v2-678b446795-hkkvv       0/2       Init:CrashLoopBackOff   738        2d
po/reviews-v3-8b796f-64lm8           0/2       Init:CrashLoopBackOff   738        2d

NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
svc/details       ClusterIP   10.104.237.100   <none>        9080/TCP   2d
svc/kubernetes    ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP    70d
svc/productpage   ClusterIP   10.100.136.14    <none>        9080/TCP   2d
svc/ratings       ClusterIP   10.105.166.190   <none>        9080/TCP   2d
svc/reviews       ClusterIP   10.110.221.19    <none>        9080/TCP   2d

NAME             ENDPOINTS                                            AGE
ep/details       10.244.0.24:9080                                     2d
ep/kubernetes    NNN.NN.NN.NNN:6443                                  70d
ep/productpage   10.244.0.45:9080                                     2d
ep/ratings       10.244.0.25:9080                                     2d
ep/reviews       10.244.0.26:9080,10.244.0.28:9080,10.244.0.29:9080   2d


PROXY INIT CRASHED CONTAINERS
------------------------------
$ docker ps -a | grep -i istio | grep -i exit

9109bafcf9e7        docker.io/istio/proxy_init@sha256:0962ff2159796a66b9d243cac82cfccb6730cd5149c91a0f64baa08f065b22f8                                       "/usr/local
/bin/prepa"   11 seconds ago       Exited (1) 10 seconds ago                           k8s_istio-init_details-v1-df5d6ff55-92jrx_default_b54d921c-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568
e45b4_740

0ed3b188d7ba        docker.io/istio/proxy_init@sha256:0962ff2159796a66b9d243cac82cfccb6730cd5149c91a0f64baa08f065b22f8                                       "/usr/local
/bin/prepa"   27 seconds ago       Exited (1) 26 seconds ago                           k8s_istio-init_reviews-v2-678b446795-hkkvv_default_b557b5a5-0dcd-11e8-8de9-005056
8e45b4_740

893fcec0b01e        docker.io/istio/proxy_init@sha256:0962ff2159796a66b9d243cac82cfccb6730cd5149c91a0f64baa08f065b22f8                                       "/usr/local
/bin/prepa"   About a minute ago   Exited (1) About a minute ago                       k8s_istio-init_reviews-v1-5845b57d57-2cjvn_default_b555bb75-0dcd-11e8-8de9-005056
8e45b4_740

a2a036273402        docker.io/istio/proxy_init@sha256:0962ff2159796a66b9d243cac82cfccb6730cd5149c91a0f64baa08f065b22f8                                       "/usr/local
/bin/prepa"   About a minute ago   Exited (1) About a minute ago                       k8s_istio-init_productpage-v1-85f65888f5-xdkt6_default_b579277b-0dcd-11e8-8de9-00
50568e45b4_740

520beb6779e0        docker.io/istio/proxy_init@sha256:0962ff2159796a66b9d243cac82cfccb6730cd5149c91a0f64baa08f065b22f8                                       "/usr/local
/bin/prepa"   About a minute ago   Exited (1) About a minute ago                       k8s_istio-init_reviews-v3-8b796f-64lm8_default_b559d9ef-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45
b4_740

91a0f41f5fde        docker.io/istio/proxy_init@sha256:0962ff2159796a66b9d243cac82cfccb6730cd5149c91a0f64baa08f065b22f8                                       "/usr/local
/bin/prepa"   3 minutes ago        Exited (1) 3 minutes ago                            k8s_istio-init_ratings-v1-668b7f9ddc-9nhcw_default_b55128a5-0dcd-11e8-8de9-005056
8e45b4_740



PROXY PROCESSES FOR EACH ISTIO COMPONENT
-----------------------------------------

$ docker ps | grep -vi exit | grep proxy
4d9b37839e44        docker.io/istio/proxy@sha256:3a9fc8a72faec478a7eca222bbb2ceec688514c95cf06ac12ab6235958c6883c                                            "/usr/local/bin/pilot"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_istio-proxy_reviews-v2-678b446795-hkkvv_default_b557b5a5-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0

1c72e3a990cb        docker.io/istio/proxy@sha256:3a9fc8a72faec478a7eca222bbb2ceec688514c95cf06ac12ab6235958c6883c                                            "/usr/local/bin/pilot"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_istio-proxy_productpage-v1-85f65888f5-xdkt6_default_b579277b-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0
f6ffcaf4b24b        docker.io/istio/proxy@sha256:3a9fc8a72faec478a7eca222bbb2ceec688514c95cf06ac12ab6235958c6883c                                            "/usr/local/bin/pilot"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_istio-proxy_reviews-v1-5845b57d57-2cjvn_default_b555bb75-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0
b66b7ab90a2d        docker.io/istio/proxy@sha256:3a9fc8a72faec478a7eca222bbb2ceec688514c95cf06ac12ab6235958c6883c                                            "/usr/local/bin/pilot"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_istio-proxy_ratings-v1-668b7f9ddc-9nhcw_default_b55128a5-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0
08bf2370b5be        docker.io/istio/proxy@sha256:3a9fc8a72faec478a7eca222bbb2ceec688514c95cf06ac12ab6235958c6883c                                            "/usr/local/bin/pilot"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_istio-proxy_reviews-v3-8b796f-64lm8_default_b559d9ef-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0
0c10d8d594bc        docker.io/istio/proxy@sha256:3a9fc8a72faec478a7eca222bbb2ceec688514c95cf06ac12ab6235958c6883c                                            "/usr/local/bin/pilot"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_istio-proxy_details-v1-df5d6ff55-92jrx_default_b54d921c-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0
6134fa756f35        docker.io/istio/proxy@sha256:3a9fc8a72faec478a7eca222bbb2ceec688514c95cf06ac12ab6235958c6883c                                            "/usr/local/bin/pilot"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_istio-proxy_istio-pilot-69cc4dd5cb-fglsg_istio-system_5ecf54b6-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0
9a18ea74b6bf        docker.io/istio/proxy@sha256:3a9fc8a72faec478a7eca222bbb2ceec688514c95cf06ac12ab6235958c6883c                                            "/usr/local/bin/pilot"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_istio-proxy_istio-mixer-69f48ddb6c-d4ww2_istio-system_5e8801ab-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0
5db18d722bb1        docker.io/istio/proxy@sha256:3a9fc8a72faec478a7eca222bbb2ceec688514c95cf06ac12ab6235958c6883c                                            "/usr/local/bin/pilot"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_istio-ingress_istio-ingress-f7ff9dcfd-fl85s_istio-system_5ed6333d-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0




$ docker ps | egrep -iv "proxy|pause|kube-|etcd|defaultbackend|ingress"
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                                                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

Docker Containers for the apps (These seem to have started up without issues)
------------------------------
61951f88b83c        docker.io/istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v2@sha256:e390023aa6180827373293747f1bff8846ffdf19fdcd46ad91549d3277dfd4ea                     "/bin/sh -c '/opt/ibm"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_reviews_reviews-v2-678b446795-hkkvv_default_b557b5a5-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0

18d2137257c0        docker.io/istio/examples-bookinfo-productpage-v1@sha256:ce983ff8f7563e582a8ff1adaf4c08c66a44db331208e4cfe264ae9ada0c5a48                 "/bin/sh -c 'python p"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_productpage_productpage-v1-85f65888f5-xdkt6_default_b579277b-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0

5ba97591e5c7        docker.io/istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v1@sha256:aac2cfc27fad662f7a4473ea549d8980eb00cd72e590749fe4186caf5abc6706                     "/bin/sh -c '/opt/ibm"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_reviews_reviews-v1-5845b57d57-2cjvn_default_b555bb75-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0

ed11b00eff22        docker.io/istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v3@sha256:6829a5dfa14d10fa359708cf6c11ec9022a3d047a089e73dea3f3bfa41f7ed66                     "/bin/sh -c '/opt/ibm"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_reviews_reviews-v3-8b796f-64lm8_default_b559d9ef-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0

be88278186c2        docker.io/istio/examples-bookinfo-ratings-v1@sha256:b14905701620fc7217c12330771cd426677bc5314661acd1b2c2aeedc5378206                     "/bin/sh -c 'node rat"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_ratings_ratings-v1-668b7f9ddc-9nhcw_default_b55128a5-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0

e1c749eedf3c        docker.io/istio/examples-bookinfo-details-v1@sha256:02c863b54d676489c7e006948e254439c63f299290d664e5c0eaf2209ee7865e                     "/bin/sh -c 'ruby det"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_details_details-v1-df5d6ff55-92jrx_default_b54d921c-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0


Docker Containers for Control Plane components
-----------------------------------------------
(CA: no ssl setup done)
5847934ca3c6        docker.io/istio/istio-ca@sha256:b3aaa5e5df2c16b13ea641d9f6b21f1fa3fb01b2f36a6df5928f17815aa63307                                         "/usr/local/bin/istio"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_istio-ca_istio-ca-5796758d78-md7fl_istio-system_5ed9a9e4-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0


(PILOT:
[1] W0209 19:13:58.364556       1 client_config.go:529] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.)
[2] warn    AvailabilityZone couldn't find the given cluster node
[3] warn    AvailabilityZone unexpected service-node:  invalid node type (valid types: ingress, sidecar, router in the service node "mixer~~.~.svc.cluster.local"
[4] warn    AvailabilityZone couldn't find the given cluster node
pattern 2, 3, 4 repeats)
f7a7816bd147        docker.io/istio/pilot@sha256:96c2174f30d084e0ed950ea4b9332853f6cd0ace904e731e7086822af726fa2b                                            "/usr/local/bin/pilot"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_discovery_istio-pilot-69cc4dd5cb-fglsg_istio-system_5ecf54b6-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0

(MIXER: W0209 19:13:57.948480       1 client_config.go:529] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.)
f4c85eb7f652        docker.io/istio/mixer@sha256:a2d5f14fd55198239817b6c1dac85651ac3e124c241feab795d72d2ffa004bda                                            "/usr/local/bin/mixs "   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_mixer_istio-mixer-69f48ddb6c-d4ww2_istio-system_5e8801ab-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0

(STATD EXPORTER: No issues/errors)
9fa2865b7e9b        docker.io/prom/statsd-exporter@sha256:d08dd0db8eaaf716089d6914ed0236a794d140f4a0fe1fd165cda3e673d1ed4c                                   "/bin/statsd_exporter"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               k8s_statsd-to-prometheus_istio-mixer-69f48ddb6c-d4ww2_istio-system_5e8801ab-0dcd-11e8-8de9-0050568e45b4_0
```

Answer (score 0):

This question would make a fantastic 
https://github.com/istio/issues/issues/new 
report - thanks for all the details

Can you try adding

`privileged: true`

to the container that crashes ?

Comment: I had posted the query on github day before yesterday, and got a response yesterday with a few suggestions, which I tried and it worked ! :-)
Now none of the containers are crashing, and I am able access the bookinfo apps via the ingress gateway.

Heres the url to the github post
https://github.com/istio/issues/issues/197

Answer (score 0):

@laurent-demailly, thank you for your suggestion on the privileged flag.

I had posted the query on github day before yesterday, and got a response yesterday with a few suggestions, which I tried and it worked ! :-)

Now none of the containers are crashing, and I am able access the bookinfo apps via the ingress gateway.

Heres the url to the github post:

github.com/istio/issues/issues/197